# PM2 causing performance issue with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, performance, pm2

when I run my Node js app by using `node server.js` command. It works without any performance issue. But when I start my app with `pm2 start server.js` then all the MySql queries starts taking too much time (around 1 to 2 Minutes). The problem occurs only with MySQL queries. The requests that don't execute any MySQL queries are responded without any delay. The problem is only with the APIs that includes any database interaction.

Comment: Turn on MySQL's slowlog with `long_query_time=1`.  Check the slowlog to see what is bad; then let's discuss one of the worst.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you have [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) installed, and that pm2 uses another version of node?

If so, just to test if it works fine with your current node version, try to run

```
pm2 start server.js --interpreter=~/.nvm/versions/node/`nvm current`/bin/node
```